# Play2.1: how to remove the "._EBEAN_INTERCEPT" column

Tags: jpa, playframework, playframework-2.1

my project has been taken into ebean plugin. and now i want to change the manner of orm to jpa. but after i removed all the jars from the build path and fix the compiling errors, it shows the painful error:

```
    Column "XXXX0_._EBEAN_INTERCEPT" not found;
```

where 'XXXX' is the name of the table, every table.
how can i remove the odd 'Column' and fix my project?

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'javaEbean' in build.sbt file and replace with 'javaJpa' as below.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(  
  javaJdbc,  
  javaJpa,  
  cache  
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what the problem is and why this should be an improvement so the answer can be truly helpful.